# How do I stop the Wordpress.com post editor from inserting nonbreaking spaces?

Tags: wordpress.com, html, text

The Wordpress.com post editor has an annoying habit of inserting the `&nbsp;` character in posts. This wouldn't be a problem if it inserted it appropriately, or even consistently. This is, alas, not the case; as far as I can tell, there's no pattern. It'll go for weeks at a time, barely using one; then filling a post with dozens of these things.

Sure, I could get BBEdit to strip these out, but is it possible to disable this in the first place? Even better, is it possible to set things up so that posts I get from other writers get these stripped out? (My guess, based on how their format tags fall, is that most of them use the visual editor.) Or am I just gonna have to tough this out until the site gets big enough to warrant a proper Wordpress.org installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your posts in a `div` tag, it won't affect the layout and I found that helps when WP tries to add characters to my posts

Comment: Seems to be working; I've done this with several posts, some with a decent amount of HTML formatting, some not, and it's not inserting those NBSP's. Thanks!

Comment: Just to follow up: I've been doing this for the last several weeks (three posts a week) and it works almost all of the time. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I struggled with WordPress adding characters and changing the format of posts a few years back and this is by far the simplest way to fix the formatting.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this has stopped working, over the last week. Maybe it's still working for others?

Comment: ...and now it's working again.

Comment: Have opened up a thread at Wordpress.com support: [Post editor inserts non-breaking spaces](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/post-editor-inserts-non-breaking-spaces). I'll update this question if I learn anything new. (This answer is so far the best solution to the problem.)